# Undo button - last activity

Tags: c#, winforms, events, undo

I wanted to write my own code for the "Undo" button, and I am looking for some information about some event that may be fundamental for it. I mean that I need to know **when** exactly store internal information. Event "TextChanged" for the RichTextBox is not good, I would like to store it when some action is performed, like when one does change the text to bold, or uploads the photo, etc. Is there any event that could be useful for me in that case? Cause I can't find one.

I am using Windows Forms.

EDIT:
@demo: The subject you linked to gives an idea how "undo" works. I already know it, what I need is to **how to determine** that the RichTextBox state has changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement 'undo' operation in .net windows application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800940/how-to-implement-undo-operation-in-net-windows-application)

Comment: Please read my update.

Comment: You do realize that `RichTextBox` has the `Undo` method, right? What's wrong with that?

Comment: It's perfectly right, I just want to make my own that would work similarly and need some help.